# Websphere : deployment logs location?

Tags: java, deployment, jakarta-ee, websphere, ear

I am a newbie to websphere. I am trying to deploy an EAR while i get the following exception:

`DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/ejb-jar.xml`

When I searched about this error, the answers I got was to check the deployment log file to find the root cause of this error. I am not sure where the deployment logs would be. Checking under DefaultDepMgr (the default deployer) did not yield any logs. Can someone point me to the correct location of logs which would help me find the root cause of the DeploymentDescriptorLoadException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it under DefaultDepMgr/logs/dmgr/

Comment: Can you please share the path relative to the SDP70 of WAS Server ? thanks.