# Where to find the deployment logs in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: jsp, websphere

I have deployed my application in WebSphere 8.5.5 and during the deployment many of the JSP files are failed to compile. Could you please help me where can I find the deployment logs so that I can find out which JSP files are failed to compile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3912903/1031945

Answer (score 0):

You can check SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log which are located under PROFILE_HOME/logs//  and should have messages from deployment.
VG, opinions are my own and not those of my employer